# silverStripe using composer and this what's showing [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]

Tags: composer-php, silverstripe-4

I setup my AMP stack separately. Installed composer using the windows installer and  set the php.exe for composer as "c:/php/php.exe" which is where the php.exe is.
Doing  `composer create-project silverstripe/installer ./silverApp` returns this
 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  Content-Length mismatch, received 515115 bytes out of the expected 1069991

How do I fix this..?

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with one of the Packagist mirrors. It should be resolved in the meantime, but if you still encounter this issue https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/7782#issuecomment-438585301 contains some background information and provides this command to switch the mirror to use:

```
composer config repositories.packagist.org composer https://repo-eu-uk-1.packagist.org
```

You can later unset the mirror with this command:

```
composer config repositories.packagist.org --unset
```